# How do I turn each row of a user input from a ReadLine() into a seperate list of char? C#, Console

Tags: c#, console

When opening the console application, the user is supposed to paste in rows of dots and stars, all at once (It looks like a matrix). I want to make each of these rows into a seperate list. I think I know how to do it for column but can't get a hold on how I would go about it when it's about rows. Can someone help a new guy out?

Comment: I'm not quite envisioning what you are talking about (for example, a list of what).  That's why good questions here always show the code that you have tried.  Try building a [mcve] and editing your question

Comment: Help for new guyz is located in the [Help] which features [ask].  Also be sure to read [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).  Also see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Posting a sample of the code you have tried will allow someone to assist you

Answer (score 1):

Not so bad if you know a little LINQ

```
List<List<char>> lines = new List<List<char>>();

string line = string.Empty;

while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null && line != string.Empty)
{
     lines.Add(line.Select(x => x).Where(x => x != ' ').ToList());
}
```

We have a List of Lists of characters so that each "row" is represented as a "row" in this List>. Then we need to keep reading lines from the Console until it no longer returns a value. This is how we get every row the user has entered. So now we have a string `line` to process for each line read in this way. A little bit of LINQ allows us to go through each character `x` in the line, where the character `x` is not a space , and cast the result (all the non-whitespace characters) to a character list. Each time this is done we create a new row. Finally, we just add the row to the list of character rows we have, and voila. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your input is formatted, but you could use something like this to split on a space or a specific character in the .Split() method.

```
public List<string> SplitList = new List<string>();

    public void SplitByRow()
    {
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        string[] splitArray = userInput != null ? userInput.Split(' ') : null;
        SplitList = splitArray != null ? splitArray.ToList() : null;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public void Main(string res) {
    var passedValues = res.Select(x => x).ToList();   
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.